# Do caution laps count in average speed?

Tags: auto-racing

Often, when reporting the results of an automobile race, one will see a driver's average speed given.  Does this average speed include caution laps, or are they discounted for the purposes of determining time/distance?

Answer (score 4):

**The following race series use caution laps as a part of the average race speed**

I know of no race series that does not include caution laps into the average speed of the overall race.  The series listed in particular do incorporate all track time for checkered flag (start) to checkered flag (finish) into the average race speed.

- MotoGP
- Formula 1
- World Superbike
- British Superbike
- NASCAR
- World Endurance Championship
- Motocross Grand Prix
- Supercross
- British Touring Cars
- Deutsche Tourenwagen Masters
- Rolex Sports Car Series
- IRL (Indy Racing League)
- World Touring Car Championship
- FIA GT1 World Championship

Answer (score 3):

Under the FIA Formula One Official FAQs

1. Do the laps covered behind the safety car count?

Yes, all the laps covered behind the Safety Car count as part of the total distance of the race.

This is why the Monaco Grand Prix has a low average speed as there are many crashes requiring a safety car.

Comment: As an aside, I'd say that the number of slow corners and hairpins has a more to do with low average speed than crashes and safety cars. For example the [1998 Monaco Grand Prix](http://atlasf1.com/news/1999fiafaq.htm#q28) was the slowest of the season, despite there being no safety car deployed at that race.